# Windows Embedded Standard Run-Time Image Build Length

Tags: windows, embedded

I've been using XP Embedded for a while and I recently started working with Embedded Standard since that's the latest binaries for Windows Embedded and includes SP3.  Everything works just as expected and the same way as XP Embedded but the one thing that really annoys me is the length it takes to build a run-time image.  With XP Embedded I could build a run-time image in about 20 mins or less.  With Embedded Standard it takes at least 45 minutes to an hour.  I understand there are more files (SP3) files, but what really makes me wonder the most is that Target Designer sits on this file for the majority of the build:

```
Building: Windows XP Service Pack 1 Resource DLL: copying C:\Windows\System32\MUI\OCOA\xpsp1res.dll
```

So, it's taking all this time to copy 1 service pack 1 file?

Doesn't make sense, is there something I'm doing wrong with a new component or something?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure this belongs on StackOverflow.com, not here.

Comment: I thought about that and figured it wasn't programming related so I came here.. I think the line may be fuzzy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I studied the path and the MUI stands for "multilanguage user interface", so I removed the extra language support and the building of the image was done in 171 seconds, now that's tolerable, I don't know which language it was that was giving me problems.